# Java 8 filter considering multiple items of the stream

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

Consider this class:-

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class Report {
    private short value;
    private Timestamp created;
    //Getters, Setters
}
```

I have a `List` of Reports obtained from the database using `ORDER BY created DESC`.

The task is to have just the latest report from each month. I know it can be done at SQL level, but for some reason I need to do it in Java.

This is how I solved it:-

```
    /**
     * Assuming that the reports are sorted with <code>ORDER BY created DESC</code>, this method filters the list so
     * that it contains only the latest report for any month.
     *
     * @param reports Sorted list of reports
     * @return List containing not more than one report per month
     */
    public static List<Report> oneReportPerMonthFilter(List<Report> reports) {
        Map<String, Report> monthlyReports = new HashMap<>();
        reports.forEach(report -> {
            String yearMonth = getCreatedYearMonth(report);
            if (!monthlyReports.containsKey(yearMonth)) {
                monthlyReports.put(yearMonth, report);
            }
        });
        return new ArrayList<>(monthlyReports.values());
    }

    private static String getCreatedYearMonth(Report report) {
        return YearMonth
                .from(ZonedDateTime.of(report.getCreated().toLocalDateTime(), ZoneOffset.UTC))
                .toString();
    }
```

**Question 1**

Although this works as expected, I had to create a `Map` and then convert the `values` back to a `List`. Is there a better way of doing this using Java 8 Stream API? Perhaps a more "functional" way?

**Question 2**

Can the method `getCreatedYearMonth(Report report)` which converts `Timestamp` to `YearMonth` be simplified? Currently it changes `Timestamp` to `LocalDateTime` and then to `ZonedDateTime` and then to `YearMonth`.

Unit test:-

```
@Test
public void shouldFilterOutMultipleReportsPerMonth() {
    Report report1 = new Report();
    report1.setCreated(Timestamp.from(Instant.EPOCH));
    report1.setValue((short) 100);

    Report report2 = new Report();
    report2.setCreated(Timestamp.from(Instant.EPOCH.plus(10, ChronoUnit.DAYS)));
    report2.setValue((short) 200);

    Report report3 = new Report();
    report3.setCreated(Timestamp.from(Instant.EPOCH.plus(40, ChronoUnit.DAYS)));
    report3.setValue((short) 300);

    List<Report> reports = Stream.of(report3, report2, report1).collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<Report> filteredReportList = ExampleClass.oneReportPerMonthFilter(reports);
    Assert.assertEquals(2, filteredReportList.size());
    Assert.assertEquals((short) 300, (short) filteredReportList.get(0).getValue());
    Assert.assertEquals((short) 200, (short) filteredReportList.get(1).getValue());
}
```

**Edit 1**

**Answer**

Thanks to all for your answers. Using Amith's and Johannes's answers, I was able to come up with this version, which is simple and easy to read:-

```
public static List<Report> oneReportPerMonthFilter(List<Report> reports) {
    Set<YearMonth> found = new HashSet<>();
    return reports.stream()
            .filter(r -> found.add(getCreatedYearMonth(r)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static YearMonth getCreatedYearMonth(Report report) {
    return YearMonth.from(
            report.getCreated()
                    .toInstant()
                    .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
}
```

Seems like there is no quick way to convert Timestamp to YearMonth. We can take a string representation of year-month from Timestamp as shown by Amith though.

Comment: For questions like this, it's helpful to have an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (minimal, complete and verifiable example) so we can run the code ourselves and verify that our answers are correct.

Comment: @Radiodef I have provided the model class (except getters/setters which can be generated), the methods in question, and the unit test that can be run to test your solution. Please advise what else should I add.

Comment: Whatever else is necessary to make the code compile and run without much effort. I don't think your question will be closed or anything in this case, if you don't. It's just a suggestion to make it more likely that you get more better answers.

Comment: The `YearMonth` can be created directly from `LocalDateTime`. No need to convert to `ZonedDateTime` in the middle. And you may get a list of `Report` by using `Arrays.asList()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Java stream with stateful predicate like below to filter first report by month.
**NOTE:** - Don't run this with parallelStream(), as its not thread safe and also assumes the list is sorted by date to get desired result of picking first one in order for month & year.

**HIGHLIGHTS**

```
    public static List<Report> oneReportPerMonthFilter(List<Report> reports) {
            Set<String> found = new HashSet<>();
            return reports.stream().filter(r -> found.add(getCreatedYearMonth(r))).collect(Collectors.toList());    
    }

    public static String getCreatedYearMonth(Report report) {
            //Or you can use SimpleDateFormat to extract Year & Month
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(report.getCreated());
            return "" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        }
    }
```

**TESTABLE (FULL) CODE**

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ReportFilter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Report report1 = new Report();      
        report1.setCreated(Timestamp.from(Instant.EPOCH));
        report1.setValue((short) 100);

        Report report2 = new Report();
        report2.setCreated(Timestamp.from(Instant.EPOCH.plus(10, ChronoUnit.DAYS)));
        report2.setValue((short) 200);

        Report report3 = new Report();
        report3.setCreated(Timestamp.from(Instant.EPOCH.plus(40, ChronoUnit.DAYS)));
        report3.setValue((short) 300);

        Report report4 = new Report();
        report4.setCreated(Timestamp.from(Instant.EPOCH.plus(40, ChronoUnit.DAYS)));
        report4.setValue((short) 400);

        List<Report> reports = Arrays.asList(report1, report2, report3, report4);
        List<Report> filteredReports = oneReportPerMonthFilter(reports); 
        System.out.println(filteredReports);
    }

    public static List<Report> oneReportPerMonthFilter(List<Report> reports) {
        Set<String> found = new HashSet<>();
        return reports.stream().filter(r -> found.add(getCreatedYearMonth(r))).collect(Collectors.toList());    
    }

    public static String getCreatedYearMonth(Report report) {
        //Or you can use SimpleDateFormat to extract Year & Month
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(report.getCreated());
        return "" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    }
}

class Report {
    private Timestamp created;
    private short value;    

    public Timestamp getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Timestamp created){
        this.created = created;
    }


    public short getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(short value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Report [created=" + created + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful. You might want to change `Set<Object>` to `Set<String>` though. I changed it to `Set<YearMonth>` (I edited my question to add the solution that I settled at finally).

Comment: Yeah I agree. It was a quick compile to give you possible options. And thanks for summarizing your answer, it will help others for future reference. All the solutions given for Year/Month key creation are good & efficient, it wasn't a bottleneck anyways. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 4):

You should not convert the `YearMonth` to a string. Just omit the `toString()` part. Also, I was able to simplify it to this:

```
private static YearMonth getCreatedYearMonth(Report report) {
    return YearMonth.from(report.getCreated().toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
}
```

To get the result you want, you have to chain some Collectors:

```
Map<YearMonth, Report> last = reports.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> getCreatedYearMonth(r),
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Report::getCreated)),
                        Optional::get)));
```

The outer `Collector` is `groupingBy`: We want something from each `YearMonth`. The downstream collector will only see `Report`s in the same month.
The downstream `Collector` is `collectingAndThen`, because the `maxBy` collector will result in a `Optional<Report>`. But we already know that there is at least one `Report` for each month, so we just unwrap it.
The innermost collector is just getting the maximum value by the `Timestamp`.

Comment: If you want just a list of the report, you can do `List<Report> lastList = new ArrayList<>(last.values());`.

Comment: By the way, this solution works fine with parallel streams.

Comment: +1 for using `YearMonth` from `java.time`. Please note the dependency on time zone/offset: the question used the JVM default time zone, the answer uses UTC. For some report creation times the result will not be the same.

Comment: @OleV.V. This can be solved by using `YearMonth.from(report.getCreated().toLocalDateTime());`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question:

Using the standard API there isn't really a way to do what you want without creating a map; however, I did re-write to make it more idiomatic.

```
public static List<Report> oneReportPerMonthFilter2(List<Report> reports) {
    return reports.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Q50938904::getCreatedYearMonth))
        .values().stream()
            .map(p-> p.get(0))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If you are able, consider looking at StreamEx. Its an extension of the streams API.